# Django how to write this query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have models `Product` and `Category`. `Category` can have many products. (`Product` have foreign key `category`).

I need to select categories which have at least one product.

I have no idea, how to do this in Django. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Category.objects.filter(product__isnull=False)
```

Comment: Category does not have attribute 'product'.

Comment: try it! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name